# Live Online Editor (Google Wave in Simple)

Tags: javascript

Is there any free ad-hoc live meeting online editor (I think it would be AJAX/Javascript based) where I can share a URL with a friend and edit the same text online (live).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Collabedit](http://collabedit.com/) a few times and had good results, also Google Docs will do realtime shared editing as well.

Answer (score 1):

one of the zillions of [etherpad](http://etherpad.com/) clones provide such a feature or you can grab the software and host it yourself, if you need it.

this question is a good candidate for [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), btw.